# Sanity.io code input – how to add an input field for highlighted lines?

Tags: javascript, user-input, sanity

I've stuck trying to add `highlightedLines` field to Sanity.io code input. The only docs I've found yet are on [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sanity/code-input) of the module, and there is an example data model:

```
{
  _type: 'code',
  language: 'js',
  highlightedLines: [1, 2], // <--- I need to have this field accessible in sanity studio
  code: 'const foo = "bar"\nconsole.log(foo.toUpperCase())\n// BAR'
}
```

I've tried (naively) to add `fields: { foo: "array" }`  property to the "Code block" object in `blockContent.js`, but then the studio didn't compile, throwing `Cannot override 'fields' of subtypes of "object"` error.

Do I need to create new type from `code` and decorate it with additional fields separately?

```
// current blockContent.js

export default {
  title: "Block Content",
  name: "blockContent",
  type: "array",
  of: [
    {
    // ...  

    {
      type: "image",
      options: { hotspot: true },
    },
    {
      title: "Code block",
      name: "code",
      type: "code",
      options: {
        withFilename: true,
      }
    },
  ],
};
```

I'd gladly take any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can highlight a line by clicking on its line number on the left. Could be added to the documentation :)

[image: highlight code line]

Comment: Splendid! I would never figure out. It really should be mentioned in docs.